Is there a notion of a "smooth approximation" of a fractal?
The motivating example that comes to mind is the koch snowflake fractal. Given that the recursive structure of the fractal comes from injecting triangles into triangles, it seems like one could describe a sequence of smooth curves that enclose it.
For example, one could start with the circumcircle of the starting triangle,then on the second iteration define a smooth blend of the disks of this circumcircle and the circumcircles of the 3 newly introduced triangles (i.e. 2D metaballs).
And this recursive procedure can be iterated over. Over N iterations the resulting shape is smooth as it is the finite smooth union of smooth objects.
This particular procedure is not necessarily the best approximation, but it certainly is an approximation. I wonder if there's any further study on this kind of construction. Note that by smooth I do mean differentiable.

What would it mean for a smooth curve to "enclose" a fractal figure with "holes" in it, so to speak? Think of the Sierpinski triangle. "Enclosure" therefore requires a bit more definition on your part, but I suspect the ultimate answer is going to heavily depend on the type of fractal being considered.

In the case of the Koch snowflake, you could approximate each iteration as the spline interpolation (of a given arbitrary degree) of the vertices of the snowflake at that iteration. The degree of the spline specifies how smooth the approximation will be.

@H.sapiensrex this is an interesting question and something I would also like to know. This is why I am asking if there is a field of math that focuses on this kind of problem.

@StefanLafon That works indeed, but so many fractals don't have an easy set of points one can pass a spline through (and also you can't do my ball construction either).
I just wonder if there is literature on this particular topic.

@Makogan What is a "fractal"?  For every definition with which I am familiar, a generic set in (for example) $\mathbb{R}^n$ is almost certainly fractal.  Most of these sets have no real, identifiable structure.  E.g. they are not the graph of a continuous function, nor measurable, nor anything else.  The fractals which tend to get studied are those which do have nicer properties, e.g. they can be approximated by continuous functions.  It is not clear to me what you are after here.

@XanderHenderson note you said continuous function, not smooth. For example, the mandelbrot set seems like a very tricky case to try to make smooth, so is Sierpinski's triangle, or Weirestrass function. I would say a fractal is a space with non integer fractal dimension, so R^n is not a fractal.

@Makogan I was giving examples of properties which fractals generally fail to satisfy.  For your definition of "fractal" (assuming you mean something "reasonable" by fractal dimension), a generic set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is fractal.  The weird sets are the ones which are not fractal.

@XanderHenderson then perhaps the better question would be, is there field of math that studies which transformations make a smooth manifold into a fractal structure?

How do you "make a smooth manifold into a fractal structure"?  That doesn't make sense to me.

@XanderHenderson It does to me, a very simple case is once again the Koch Snowflake, it is clearly a manifold since at any iteration you can construct an isomorphism from a neighbourhood around any point into R. Moreover, it is clearly isomorphic to a circle, thus there exists a map from the snowflake to the circle.
And in fact there must exists an entire family of functions from the snowflake into any simple closed curve in R2.
Among all of the smooth simple curves in R2, there must be a few which are "better" by some metric.

You are talking about isomorphisms, which are maps which preserve a topological structure.  But the things which characterize fractality are not topological---they are metric.  In the language of category theory, "fractals" live in some category where the objects are (compact or maybe locally compact) metric spaces, and the maps are isometries (or maybe bi-Lipschitz maps). I still don't really understand what you are after here---maybe some notion of approximability by smooth curves? But for that, you need to be more specific about what kinds of fractal objects you are trying to approximate.

@XanderHenderson It seems to me that there must be some link between fractals and smooth manifolds and what I am looking for is literature on that topic. Work on how to morph one into the other and/or approximate one through the other.

Again, a generic set in a metric space is probably a fractal.  Being fractal is the default state for a set.  Most sets do not have any kinds of nice properties (they are completely pathologtical; non-measurable, non-smooth, non-continuous---whatever nice property you might come up with), and there is going to be no hope approximating them with "nicer" sets.  If you want to somehow approximate fractals with smooth maps, you need to restrict your attention to those sets which can be approximated in that way, which feels pretty circular...

@XanderHenderson there still seems to me like there must be some kind of subset of fractals for which this question is interested. For example, the famous coast of Britain problem or how hair looks like a smooth manifold with Lambertian reflection from afar but becomes more complicated the closer you look in.  The earth is a spheroid from space and an extremely rich mess when looking at it up close...
So it feels to me like there is a connection between at least some fractals and smooth manifolds. I just want to read more on that.

Fractals are interesting in that they aren't smooth, and they don't have the properties of smooth maps.  They are not really amenable to any kind of smooth analysis, and while you might be able to approximate them by smooth sets, none of the "nice" properties of those smooth approximations pass to the limit.  If you can be more specific about why you want fractals which behave like smooth manifolds (and in what way), I might be able to offer you some resources, but right now, I have no idea what you are trying to get at.  I am not sure what your goal is.

@XanderHenderson I think the two motivating cases are the earth and hair. As mentioned they are objects that behave like smooth manifolds at large scales but are completely anti-smooth the more you zoom into them (which is ironically the opposite of being smooth). I am interested in learning to model these kinds of objects.
It seems to me that these cases could be described as a manifold set plus some kind of deformation that breaks smoothness in some kind of iterable pattern.
